# How do I make a ggplot graph with different x values having different jitter?

Tags: r, ggplot2, jitter

If I want to jitter points, but my x axis has uneven intervals like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

how can I vary the widths of the jitter at different x axis values so I don't end up with overlap like this?

```
ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len)) + geom_jitter(width = 0.3,size = 4)
```

[image]

I want a way for instance to make the jitter narrow at 0.5, wider at 1, and widest at 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dirty way might be to jitter the dose before the plotting:

```
JitterSize <- rep(c(1.5, 3, 6), table(ToothGrowth$dose))
ToothGrowth $ Jitter <- jitter(ToothGrowth $ dose, JitterSize)
ggplot(data = ToothGrowth, 
       aes(x = Jitter, y=len, color = as.character(dose))) + 
geom_point(size = 4)
```

Updated based on abruh's comments.

Comment: If I do it this way is there a way I can cleanly supply manual factor assignments by dose?  For instance instead of dose*3 could I specify the factor manually as 1.5, 3, and 6?

Comment: Nevermind, I see that the way to do what I'm asking in the previous comment is to create another column with different jitter weights specified and then use that as the factor argument. Thanks!